# What configs should be required to connect .aspx online?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I'm pretty new learning c#, and ASP.NET. I want to connect the page I've written with visual studio2012 using IIS. I know how this works on local, but I don't have a clue about making this work online.

For example, when I debug my asp.net page, the directory is:

```
localhost:2791/WebForm1.aspx.
```

This project is saved on the IIS root directory, and all the configs for the IIS seems to be fine.

But when I try to access this such as, `myip/WebForm1.aspx`, it doesn't work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to host your web application in the IIS.

I am assuming that, you have correctly hosted your application in the IIS.

Now, try accessing it with address `localhost:portnumber/virtual directory`,

if you are able to access, then go ahead and read the answer below, otherwise, you simply have not hosted your app properly in IIS.

Now, to access your IIS hosted website through your IP address +Port number(if not default), you must check if Firewall has not blocked it.

For enabling access to your IIS hosted website through your IP, do this:

goto `Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Firewall\Allowed Programs` and make sure property `World Wide Web Services (HTTP)` is checked (for all the networks)

Comment: It is setted as a virtual directory but when I actually tested that, an error page comes up. When I used a simple html file to test this, it worked, but an aspx page isn't working.

Comment: see, you need to read about the error, it is possible that, your hosted app environment Application pool is set to lower dot net version i.e. 2.0 or similar and your app is built in higher dot net version. find out the error

Comment: Thanks. It was an error caused by poor configurations on the IIS service. I found out that I didn't turn on some functions for the IIS service.. T.T